# Errno 13 Permission denied: when trying to access the CSV file when script is running in backend

Tags: python

I'm trying to open the csv file when script is running but getting Error 13 Permission denied as i have scheduled my script to run in every 15 min to get the latest record in it and parallelly want to see the file as well during the run time of my script any suggestions how i can code so that i can open the file wrt running script in backend.

As Permission denied is occurred due to my csv file is opened in my local machine and my script tried to update it at the same time.

Currently i m using append method to write the data to CSV

I m trying to copy the data from website to CSV for tracking the record.

file2 = 'India.csv'

`with open(file2, 'a+', newline='') as _file1`

Comment: Try to run your python script as Administrator.

Comment: i m Running the script as Administrator then also facing issue.

Comment: What's the name of `file2` ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Actually code is working fine i have created the script which will pull the data from website and drop the data to CSV as interval of 15 minutes for tracking the record.

Comment: The file cannot be opened at another source when it is being used by one source.Probably close th file from one source and reopen at next source.

Comment: I got stuck in permission denied issue, actually i want to open the csv file at the same time when my script is running at backend.

Comment: i checked in google someone has explained to use chomd for accessing the file at the same time when script is running in backend. not sure how to use it

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is in windows. If you open a file with any tool that keeps the filehandle open after its read, file is locked and only thing you can do is close the file in that application.

Comment: Yes i m doing this in windows is there no way to open the file at the same time of running script ? as i know when one source is using the file another source will get denied error when file is not closed by main source but i m just looking that solution if i can fix that because i want to use csv file data to create a graph of the record at the run time of my script.

Comment: If the application opening the file  for reading, just reads the whole file into buffer and then closes the filehandle, file wont be locked.  If its your own python code for example, just read the whole file into memory and call close() on the filehandle.. If its some external application/tool, you might be out of luck.